# write_pandas from Dataframe to Snowflake insert - Can only convert 1-dimensional array values

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the Can only convert 1-dimensional array values error when trying to use write_pandas from the dataframe below

Also I was assuming that my dataframe was set up appropriately, as I have followed Snowflakes documentation on using a DF to insert with write_pandas.

[image]

printed the dataframe repr:

[image]

```
write_pandas(connection_String, dataframe, table_name,database='SB', schema = 'SBB',quote_identifiers=False)
```

it is also telling me that 'Conversion failed for column SRC_XML with type object') my snowflake table is set to type variant, not sure it should be something else...or if i can convert SRC_XML to another type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried for a while to reformat the first column of the dataframe to Str, and it wasnt working, finally was able to add

```
df['SRC_XML']=df['SRC_XML'].astype(str)
```

and it finally worked. I think the Object type that the dataframe column was not working with the data type variant in the snowflake table